# Trying to deploy node.js app with mongoDB on EC2

Tags: node.js, mongodb

is there a GOOD tutorial or resource that I can read to deploy node.js app with mongoDB on EC2 or on linux(ubuntu) server?? I have read several of the tutorials on the web but there were not clear one that helped me. I have installed npm, node.js and all pacakages I'm using for my app and cloned my app from git repo. Tried to run it using

```
nodejs server.js
```

where "server.js" my app server, it crashes because my mongoDB. How do I properly setup mongoDB and node.js app. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digital Ocean's tutorials are pretty good:

[How to install MongoDB on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[How to set up Node on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04)